# What's the best way to watch the ServiceHost while debugging inside a WCF service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, debugging

What's the best way to watch the service host while debugging inside a WCF service?  I'd like to know the binding properties and other info about the service host.

I was hoping there would be something like ServiceHost.GetCurrent but obviously that isn't right, and Googling around just yields articles about how to configure or tweak a service host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.Host` to access the currently running ServiceHost object.  `OperationContext` also contains other goodies, such as `IncomingMessageHeaders` for one example.